# Reading a column file of x y z into table in Lua

Tags: lua

Been trying to find my way through Lua, so I have a file containing N lines of numbers, 3 per line, it is actually x,y,z coordinates. I could make it a CSV file and use some Lua CSV parser, but I guess it's better if I learn how to do this regardless.

So what would be the best way to deal with this? So far I am able to read each line into a table line by the code snippet below, but 1) I don't know if this is a string or number table, 2) if I print tbllinesx[1], it prints the whole line of three numbers. I would like to be able to have tbllines[1][1], tbllines[1][2] and tbllines[1][3] corresponding to the first 3 number of 1st line of my file.

```
local file = io.open("locations.txt")
local tbllinesx = {}
local i = 0
if file then
for line in file:lines() do
 i = i + 1
 tbllinesx[i] = line
end
file:close()
else
error('file not found')
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Programming in Lua https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html

> You can call read with multiple options; for each argument, the
>   function will return the respective result. Suppose you have a file
>   with three numbers per line:
>
> **6.0       -3.23     15e12**
>
> **4.3       234       1000001**
>
> ... Now you want to print the maximum of each line. You can read all three numbers in a single call to read:

```
while true do
  local n1, n2, n3 = io.read("*number", "*number", "*number")
  if not n1 then break end
  print(math.max(n1, n2, n3))
end
```

> In any case, you should always consider the alternative of reading the
>   whole file with option "*all" from io.read and then using
>   gfind to break it up:

```
local pat = "(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s+"
for n1, n2, n3 in string.gfind(io.read("*all"), pat) do
  print(math.max(n1, n2, n3))
end
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to modify this to put the numbers into table fields on your own.

If you're using three captures you can just use table.pack to create your line table with three entries.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only have valid lines in your data file (locations.txt) all you need is change the line:

```
tbllinesx[i] = line
```

to:

```
tbllinesx[i] = { line:match '(%d+)%s+(%d+)%s+(%d+)' }
```

This will put each of the three space-delimited numbers into its own spot in a table for each line separately.

Edit: The repeated `%d+` part of the pattern will need to be adjusted according to your actual input. `%d+` assumes plain integers, you need something more involved for possible minus sign (`%-?%d+`) and for possible dot (`%-?%d-%.?%d+`), and so on.  Of course the easy way would be to grab everything that is not space (`%S+`) as a potential number.